# Visual Studio Web Deploy not publishing all Files

Tags: iis-7

When I publish my ASP.net MVC 3.0 Application to IIS 7 using Visual Studio Web Deploy settings one Partial View File is not updated.

Is it possible to debug why it failed for one particular file?

Comment: I know this is old, but this issue is very likely tied to the files having the same size before and after the changes.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Select the view that is not publishing to server,
go to properties (click F4) of the view 
under properties 
check the properties set for it:

1. **Build Action** : this should be **Content**
2. **Copy to Output Directory**: this should be like the other file are configured (I believe it should be **Do not copy**)

Then publish it.

Comment: Thanks HaBo. Unfortunately I already had those settings so it didn't work, however I deleted the existing files from the server entirely and re-published and that worked.

Comment: I hadn't used the publish stuff in years as I prefer complete control over my builds.... However I am on contract job were that is what the manager wanted and when it didn't include a newly added folder / files, Your solution fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't happen often, but when it does it gets me every time. Usually when I add the view using a different method.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I ended up renaming the partial view and that got it working

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I eventually fixed it by tweaking my publish profile in the file `Properties\Publish Profiles\ReleaseProfile.pubxml.user`.

There was a line in that file that referenced the file that wouldn't publish:

```
<File Include="Online.master">
    <publishTime>01/01/0001 00:00:00</publishTime>
</File>
```

I changed the date to one that was still in the past but wasn't ancient:

```
<File Include="Online.master">
    <publishTime>01/01/2020 00:00:00</publishTime>
</File>
```

and the file published successfully on my next attempt.

Comment: Good tip.  I checked the pubxml.user file and in my case the date for my specific file was written in UK format (dd/MM/yyyy) while all the other dates were in US format (MM/dd/yyyy).  (I'm in the UK)

Answer (score 0):

for me there was this line in .pubxml file, be sure to check the file contents as some settings are not visible from the configuration editor:

```xml
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Scripts/plugins;Content/icons;fonts</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me right click on file and publish the file directly resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Visual Studio 2022 was to right-click the file/folder in question and publish that separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had manually edited the Target Location and left off the colon after the drive letter. It never gave an error but never published.